# How do I update an Old element with a new one in C#/XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, xaml

Basically what I want to do is: Download a new XML file and replace some elements with the old one, For example replace this code:

```
<Run x:Name="Degree" Text="15"/>
```

with current degree, which is

```
<temperature value="280.15" min="278.15" max="281.15" unit="kelvin"/>
```

but I don't know how to do that. Here's my code I'm stuck with:

```
using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
{
    string url = string.Format("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
    var xml = web.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Comment: You need to bind your data to your WPF window. First convert the xml into some object form and then bind the object to your window as a DataContext. There are simpler ways, use the control name in code-behind and bind the value to the Run or TextBlock element.

Comment: The `x:Name` implies the original "code" is XAML. But you are saying you want to replace that with XML. How, _exactly_, do you expect that to work? Wouldn't it be better to follow normal MVVM practices and keep your data (the XML) entirely isolated from the view (the XAML)? At best, your question is too broad, and frankly it's not even clear what it is you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

            XElement temperature = doc.Descendants("temperature").FirstOrDefault();
            temperature.SetAttributeValue("value", 281);

            string oldXml = "<Root xmlns:x=\"abc\"><Run x:Name=\"Degree\" Text=\"15\"/></Root>";

            XDocument oldDoc = XDocument.Parse(oldXml);
            XElement run = oldDoc.Descendants("Run").FirstOrDefault();

            run.ReplaceWith(temperature);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I set  the value ```<Run x:Name="Degree" Text="15"/>``` from my code to ```temperature``` one?